# Setup a Postfix outgoing BCC based on SMTP username (not sending email address)?

Tags: postfix

Our goal is to have a copy of any email sent by a specific SMTP **user account** bcc'd to another email address.

With Postfix, we can setup an outgoing **email address** to always BCC another address on messages that are sent.

This can be done with a line in `main.cf`:

```
sender_bcc_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sender_bcc
```

And then in `/etc/postfix/sender_bcc`:

```
user@company.com bcc@company.com
```

But if the user simply changes thier outgoing mail settings to send mail as `user1@company.com`, the BCC breaks. What the user can't change, however, is their SMTP username.

So we really need a way to setup Postfix to create a BCC when a message is sent by an SMTP user logged in as `user`, regardless of what email address that person claims to have.

Is this possible? How?

Comment: Why do you even allow users to send from other email addresses?

Answer (score 4):

You may use [reject_sender_login_mismatch](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#reject_sender_login_mismatch) to force match between smtp auth and envelope sender address.  It may deliver solution acceptable for most situations.

Comment: I agree that this would be the correct answer. Please explain this a little, though.

Comment: It looks like there may be some additional setup required for this, since it relies on an SMTP username to email lookup table, `smtpd_sender_login_maps`. I wonder if there is a way to check if the user part of the email addresses matches the SMTP username without a lookup table (or with a regular expression)?